# Count consecutive occurence of element in collection

Tags: clojure, nested-loops, find-occurrences

What is the idiomatic way to get something like that?

```
(fn [coll] (function body) [1 0 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 -1])
-> [1 1 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 5 4 3 2 1 1 1 1]
```

I can only do this in this way.

```
(fn [coll] 
  (loop [i 0 r []]
    (if (< i (count coll))
      (let [elem (nth coll i)
            cc (loop [j 1]
                 (if (< (+ i j) (dec (count coll)))
                   (let [nelem (nth coll (+ i j))]
                     (if (= elem nelem)
                       (recur (inc j))
                       j))
                   j))]
        (recur (inc i) (conj r cc)))
      r)))
```

Comment: The answer should surely be `(1 1 3 4 5 1 1 1)`. No?

Comment: My English is definitely not perfect, but my code does exactly what I expect from him. Perhaps my description is bad. I want to compare only the elements after item.

Comment: Suggested opening: *How do you map a sequence to - at each point - a count of the run of equal items ahead of the item, including the item itself?*

Comment: Correction: omit the `dec` in line 6. It causes on-off errors when the sequence ends on a repeated item: on `[1 1]`, it produces `[1 1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifying @noisesmith's neat solution to what we thought the problem was:

```
(defn countdown-runs [s]
  (->> s
       (partition-by identity)
       (map count)
       (mapcat #(range % 0 -1))))
```

For example,

```
(countdown-runs [1 0 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 -1])
; (1 1 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 5 4 3 2 1 1 1 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Supposing your output is what you want, the answer should be

```
(mapcat #(reverse (range 1 (inc %)))
      (map count (partition-by identity [1 0 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 -1])))
```

First do

```
(map count (partition-by identity [1 0 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 -1]))
```

to get a the count of each consecutive elements, and then for each of the count, supply a list from the number counting down to 1. Then `mapcat` the nested sequence together.

Comment: please use `(mapcat #(reverse ...) ...)` instead of `(flatten (map #(reverse ...) ...))`, flatten is almost always the wrong thing because it can easily destroy nested structure of  an input. It can usually (as in this case) be replaced with mapcat.

Comment: Another hint: (style rather than accuracy here) - to be more idiomatic you can replace `(+ 1 %)` with `(inc %)` - same number of characters but the usage is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Although this doesn't provide exactly what was requested by OP, you may end up on this page when looking for a way of counting consecutive elements in a collection.

With transducers in Clojure 1.8 we can do something like this:

```
(defn runs
  ([]
   (runs identity))
  ([f]
   (comp (partition-by f)
         (map (juxt (comp f first) count))))
  ([f xs]
   (into [] (runs f) xs)))
```

That will allow us to create a transducer with a given partitioning function, or when called with both the partitioning function and a collection return a vector of realised values.

An example of its use:

```
(runs :name [{:name "John" :age 22}
             {:name "John" :age 44}
             {:name "Mary" :age 33}
             {:name "Lee" :age 99}
             {:name "Lee" :age 55}])

;; => [["John" 2] ["Mary" 1] ["Lee" 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can tidy up the offered solution in several ways:

- Instead of index `i`, use the sub-vector that starts at `i` as an argument in the outer loop. This makes the code easier to understand.
- For brevity, use `(v j)` instead of `(nth v j)` to get the `j`th element of `v`.
- Use `and` to simplify the control structure of the inner loop.
- (And - while we are at it - remove the `dec` that causes one-off
  errors for sequences ending on a repeated value.)

This gives us

```
(defn op-s [v] 
  (loop [v v, r []]
    (if (seq v)
      (let [elem (v 0)
            cc (loop [j 1]
                 (if (and (< j (count v)) (= elem (v j)))
                   (recur (inc j))
                   j))]
        (recur (subvec v 1) (conj r cc)))
      r)))
```

This can still be slow. For a run of length n, it performs the inner loop about n<sup>2</sup>/2 times. We can speed this up. Once we have found a run, we can count down from its length, as the lazy versions do.

```
(defn op-s [v] 
  (loop [v v, r []]
    (if (seq v)
      (let [elem (v 0)
            cc (loop [j 1]
                 (if (and (< j (count v)) (= elem (v j)))
                   (recur (inc j))
                   j))
            rr (loop [r r, i cc] (case i, 0 r, (recur (conj r i) (dec i))))]
        (recur (subvec v cc) rr))
      r)))
```